# How to move a selection such that a chosen base vertex aligns with an end vertex?

Tags: modeling, mesh, add-on, transforms

I know that the [SnapUtilities Move add-on](https://gumroad.com/l/IaqQf) had this functionality in previous versions of Blender, but it is not compatible with Blender 2.82. I need an add-on or workflow in Blender 2.82 that allows me to do this.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Pictures and descriptions are very welcome. I do not know what a "base" vertex is, nor how it is different from an "end" vertex.

Comment: To be more precise, suppose I have selected a group of vertices. I wish to choose one of the selected vertices (the "base" or "reference" vertex) and translate it to another vertex in my model (the "end" vertex), while simultaneously translating all of the vertices in the selected group in the same direction.

Comment: Okay. You can do this by turning on the Vertex Snapping option in the standard way, and in the options section for it at the top of the screen, click the button called *Active*. This will make only the active vertex respect the snap settings. Just make sure that the vertex which you want to have this behavior was the final one in your group of vertices to be selected. Otherwise, it won't be the active one.

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly!